# Dynamic dataframe schema construction in Apache Pyspark v2.3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A toy example works fine, where its schema is defined using a static definition.  The dynamically defined schema throws error, but why, and how to fix? They seem identical.

Statically defined:

```
XXX = sc.parallelize([('kygiacomo', 0, 1), ('namohysip', 1, 0)])
schema = StructType([
    StructField("username",StringType(),True),
    StructField("FanFiction",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("nfl",IntegerType(),True)])
print(schema)
df = sess.createDataFrame(XXX, schema)
df.show()
```

Output which is good:

```
StructType(List(StructField(username,StringType,true),StructField(FanFiction,IntegerType,true),StructField(nfl,IntegerType,true)))
+---------+----------+---+
| username|FanFiction|nfl|
+---------+----------+---+
|kygiacomo|         0|  1|
|namohysip|         1|  0|
+---------+----------+---+
```

Dynamically-defined:

```
print(XXX.collect())
username_field = [StructField('username', StringType(), True)]
int_fields = [StructField(str(i), IntegerType(), True) for i in itemids.keys()]
schema = StructType(username_field + int_fields)
print(schema)
df = sess.createDataFrame(XXX, schema)
df.show()
```

Output which throws an error on df.show:

```
[('kygiacomo', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), ('namohysip', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ('immortalis', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), ('403and780', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), ('SDsc0rch', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ('shitpostlord4321', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), ('scarletcrawford', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)]
StructType(List(StructField(username,StringType,true),StructField(FanFiction,IntegerType,true),StructField(nfl,IntegerType,true),StructField(alteredcarbon,IntegerType,true),StructField(The_Donald,IntegerType,true),StructField(marvelstudios,IntegerType,true),StructField(hockey,IntegerType,true)))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: field FanFiction: IntegerType can not accept object 0 in type <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I cannot see what the code is doing differently. Can you?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Based on the exception:

  > TypeError: field FanFiction: IntegerType can not accept object 0 in type

  your data contains objects of type `numpy.int64`.
- Spark SQL API in general doesn't support `numpy` types (check [SPARK-12157](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12157), [SPARK-6857](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6857) and other JIRA tickets).
- The problem is not reproducible with examples you have provided.
- But it is consistent with your previous questions ([How to create a tuple from list or array without code generation in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50844489), [How to convert numpy array elements to spark RDD column values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50804431)), which clearly show you extract data from `pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix` / `pyspark.mllib.linalg.Vector`.

  By default all value extracted from `Vectors` are represented using `numpy` types.
- Hence the error.

Now, [the answer to your previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50804559) question already shows one of the possible solutions - convert data to standard Python types using `tolist`.

Alternatively convert each entry directly calling corresponding `builtins` functions (`int`, `float` on each record in the row).